# What is wrong with my operator += of the binary search tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have some lines of code about a binary search tree (BSTreeBag) which I can not quite figure out.

The "operator +=(const BSTreeBag& addend)" requires to insert what's in the addend into the current tree we have. If the current tree we have is the same with "addend" we need to double our tree(to make duplicates of all items in the tree)

Here is my code

```
template <class ItemType>
void BSTreeBag<ItemType>::operator +=(const BSTreeBag& addend)
{
    if(this==&addend)//This works
    {
        binary_tree_node<ItemType>* addroot_ptr=root_ptr;//create a pointer
                                                         //that points to the current tree 
        insert_all(addroot_ptr);//This is a helper function that insert 
                                //every item of the addend into the current tree. It works fine.
    }
    else
    {
        insert_all(addend.root_ptr);
    }
}
```

The lines of code works perfectly whenever it is not doing self-assignment. It always stops at the line

```
insert_all(addroot_ptr);
```

without giving any information about segmentation fault or other problem. Could someone explain what is going on?

Comment: You are aware that your operator is declared (and defined) wrong? It should return a reference to the object instance (e.g. `*this`).

Comment: Also, why create a temporary pointer instead of passing `root_ptr` directly?

Comment: I think if I use the root_ptr, the object it points will change. root_ptr is the pointer pointing at the root. It should not change.

Comment: Also I think the function is void it does not need to return anything. Like I said the problem is in the "if" part, everything else works fine.

Comment: Aren't they doing the same thing, self assignment or not? I think something is wrong with the insert_all().

Comment: If the "*this" is not equal to "addend" the insert_all works fine and I tested.

Comment: All assignment operator should return a reference to the object being assigned to, otherwise you can't chain assignments like e.g. `a = b += c`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very likely problem is that you have an infinite loop when you add one tree to itself. Like in, you add nodes while iterating over the tree, but since there are new nodes being added you continue iterating and adding them, ad infinitum.

Lets give an example with a simple list. Lets say you have the following list:

```
root -> A
```

Now if you try to add the list to itself, you iterate over the list from the root pointer, finding the node `A`, so you add that. Now your list looks like

```
root -> A -> A
```

You continue the iteration and find... node `A` (again), and so you add it:

```
root -> A -> A -> A
```

And so on and so on.

You should probably create a completely new tree from `root_ptr` and then add that.

Comment: I see what you mean. I did it and it did pass. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what mine looks like (I think both the instructions AND the test file are a little wack):

```
template <class ItemType>
void BSTreeBag<ItemType>::operator+=(const BSTreeBag& addend)
{
    if (this != &addend)  
        insert_all(addend.root_ptr);
    else
    {
        BSTreeBag<ItemType> new_bst = addend;
        insert_all(new_bst.root_ptr);
        tree_clear(new_bst.root_ptr);
    }
}
```